# Swift 3 : Add SearchBar to UIViewController

Tags: filter, swift3, uicollectionview, searchbar

I am trying to add a search/filter option to a navigation bar in Swift 3. Currently, I am pushing to the current UICollectionView from previous views, all of which are on a NavigationViewController stack.

In the current UICollectionViewController, I have set up a UISearchBar object like so:

```
let searchBar: UISearchBar = {
    let sb = UISearchBar()
    sb.placeholder = "Enter search term"
    return sb
}()
```

And inside collectionViewController, viewdidload() I set up the following:

```
// searchbar
let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(searchBar)


searchBar.anchor(top: navBar?.topAnchor, left: navBar?.leftAnchor   , bottom: navBar?.bottomAnchor, right: navBar?.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0  )
```

The anchoring is done through a custom extension, though I do not believe it effects anything, but is as follows:

```
extension UIView{
    // anchor
    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?,paddingTop: CGFloat, paddingLeft: CGFloat, paddingBottom: CGFloat, paddingRight: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat){

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if let top = top{
            self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop).isActive = true
        }
        if let left = left{
            self.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: paddingLeft).isActive = true
        }
        if let bottom = bottom{
            bottom.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: paddingBottom).isActive = true
        }
        if let right = right{
            rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -paddingRight).isActive = true
        }
        if width != 0{
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        }
        if height != 0{
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
        }

    }
}
```

However, when I load the corresponding uicollectionviewcontrollers, I am not able to see the searchbar in the navigationController navBar area. Is there something else that needs to be set in order for it to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a `frame` for your `UISearchBar`. Try this:

```
let searchBar: UISearchBar = {
    let sb = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 44))    //change the width & height according to your needs.
    sb.placeholder = "Enter search term"
    return sb
}
```